# Ubuntu Server Font Anti Aliasing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, terminal

I have looked every where for this but couldn't find a fix,
I installed ubuntu server 20.04 x86 on VirtualBox

[Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qnt3.png)

But I noticed that the text looks extremely sharp (Aliased) in the terminal
I know I can use putty ssh to access the VM with clearer text
but I would like to access it the VirtualBox way

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvVhm.png)

Conclusion: how can I make the text anti aliased and nice to look at?

Comment: That's the framebuffer console. I don't think this is possible (except high DPI with larger fonts of course).